# Elasticsearch Kibana integration Connecton Failed

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Recently I upgraded elasticsearch 1.4.2 to 1.5.2 that time kibana worked fine.but recently dud to high memory pressure on servers elasticsearch process killed automatically by linux OOM Killer.from that point onwards my kibana 3.1.2 is not working I added security rules also still getting connectionFailed exception. Please suggest me how to solve this what could be the reason for kibana not connecting to elasticsearch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit your elasticsearch.yml and add these two lines:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: http://localhost:8000        --->   ( Your kibana link)
```

Now restart your elasticsearch and open your kibana 3. It will work fine.

Comment: Yes I Added these properties still my es not connecting to kibana

Comment: You should not use elasticsearch 1.4 or higher for kibana 3. Then it wont work. Just try previous version of elasticsearch and then try. Dont forget to add these two lines in yml file.